# Simple regex for comma

Tags: php, regex

Hello can someone help me with this regex please

here is my $lang_file:

```
define(words_picture,"Снимка");
define(words_amount,"бр.");
define(words_name,"Име");
define(words_price_piece,"Ед. цена");
define(words_total,"Обща цена");
define(words_del,"Изтрий");
define(words_delivery,"Доставка,но няма");
```

this is my code :

```
$fh = fopen($lang_file, 'r');
$data = str_replace($rep,"",fread($fh, filesize($lang_file)));
fclose($fh); 
preg_match_all('/define\((.*?)\)/i', $data,$defines,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

when i print $defines i get this :

```
[0] => words_picture,"Снимка"
[1] => words_amount,"бр."
[2] => words_name,"Име"
[3] => words_price_piece,"Ед. цена"
[4] => words_total,"Обща цена"
[5] => words_del,"Изтрий"
[6] => words_delivery,"Доставка" //here is the part that is missing and i need it :-)
```

so when there is a comma inside the string it breaks the string there, and doesn't return correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(koko.*?)` as the match.  That'll return `koko` for `koko,goko`.  If you want it to return `koko,goko`, remove the `?`. Make it `(koko.*)`. That will return `koko,goko` for `koko,goko`.

Here's a site that I use to test my regex against a number of cases:

http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html

based on your edit I'd say you're looking for `(koko.*)`.  If your code worked for everything else, use this:

```
preg_match_all('\(/define.*)\)/i', $data,$defines,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: define(top_menu_item_1,"Начало");
define(top_menu_item_2,"Категории");
define(top_menu_item_3,"Промоции");
define(top_menu_item_4,"Най-продавани");
define(top_menu_item_5,"Препоръчано");
define(top_menu_item_6,"За нас");
define(top_menu_item_7,"Кошница");

this is part of my file which I load, i just need to take each define with its value so i can make an array of all of them. But when there is an comma inside it doesn't return proper value for the defined. 

//the regex site is cool ;-)

Comment: @Izopi4a, please edit your question and add this info there.  It's impossible to make sense of big chunks of code in comments.

Comment: hopefully its better now :-)

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but if I understand what's going on, try removing the question mark.  If that doesn't work try encapsulating the entire define match in parenthesis. so: preg_match_all('/define\((.*)\)/i', $data,$defines,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

Comment: nope, it doesn't help removing the "?", actualy it doesn't look it changes a thing

Comment: put the whole expression in parenthesis and remove the ?: (koko.*)